# Search for a keyword as a noun

Tags: python, nltk

```
que = ("What's the weather like?")
lines_list = tokenize.sent_tokenize(que)
    for text in lines_list:
        tokenizer = word_tokenize(text)
        nouns = nltk.pos_tag(tokenizer)
        chunked = ne_chunk(nouns)
        print(chunked) #(S What/WP 's/VBZ the/DT weather/NN like/IN ?/.)
if ("weather/NN") in chunked:
    print("I found weather as noun")
```

If you run this code, it would not seem to recognize that "weather/NN" is in chunked and I can't see why this happens.Is it something wrong with my code?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My guess is that `chunked` is not a string, so a substring search isn't going to work. (And it's definitely not a sequence of strings, because otherwise it would have quotes around the values and commas between them when printed out, which is the only other thing that might work with `"whether/NN" in…`.)

Comment: You can either read the docs instead of guessing, or debug it by doing something like `for chunk in chunked: print(type(chunk), chunk)` and see what the values actually are. Which should tell you what you actually need to be looking for.

Comment: @abarnert chunked is an actual string while nouns is an array that does the same thing.This is the form of it "[('What', 'WP'), ("'s", 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('weather', 'NN'), ('like', 'IN'), ('?', '.')]'.I also tried to print what you said and it gave me this "<class 'tuple'> ('What', 'WP')
<class 'tuple'> ("'s", 'VBZ')
<class 'tuple'> ('the', 'DT')
<class 'tuple'> ('weather', 'NN')
<class 'tuple'> ('like', 'IN')
<class 'tuple'> ('?', '.')
".From what I see i think that chunked is an actual string

Comment: `chunked` is _not_ an actual string. Why do you think that it is? If it were, `for chunk in chunked:` would give you characters, not two-element tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `chunked` is not a string, but a sequence of two-element tuples:

```
[('What', 'WP'), ("'s", 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('weather', 'NN'), ('like', 'IN'), ('?', '.')]
```

So, that tuple is what you should be checking for:

```
if ("weather", "NN") in chunked:
    print("I found weather as noun")
```

---

More generally, you can debug this by looking at what the actual values are, instead of just printing out their `str` representations. For example:

```
for chunk in chunked:
    print(type(chunk), chunk)
```

… is how you discover that it's a sequence of tuples, because it shows:

```
<class 'tuple'> ('What', 'WP')
```

… while a string would show:

```
<class 'str'> W
<class 'str'> h
<class 'str'> a
```

… because strings are sequences of characters, not sequences of tuples.

---

Those look like tuples of strings. But if you want to check that for sure:

```
for chunk, typ in chunked:
    print(type(chunk), chunk, chunk(typ), typ)
```

If they're strings, you'll get something like:

```
<class 'str'> 'What' <class 'str'> 'WP'
```

… and then the code above will work. If you instead see something like:

```
<class 'nltk._spam.Eggs'> 'What' <class 'str'> 'WP'
```

… then you probably can't just do `("weather", "NN")`; you have to look at how to create an `Eggs` object.

Answer (score 0):

chunked is a chunk structure, it has the `__str__()` or `__repr__()` method overridden so that it prints as a nice string but it is not, itself, a string so you can't see if another string is `in` it. Try `if ("weather/NN") in str(chunked):`.

Comment: Converting a sequence to a string so you can do a substring search on its repr is not a good idea.

Comment: I know Stack doesn't like to say Thanks, but I will.So thanks.It made me an overall idea about this and understanding it better.

Comment: @abarnert can you please explain the disadvantages of this method?

Comment: Any particular reason that's a bad idea in this case? And regardless, it looks like `if ("weather","NN") in chunked` is a viable option

Comment: @tuddyftw the `__repr__()` method can be overwritten to output a string that includes information in addition to anything that might be contained in the actual object we want to print.

In a bit of a ridiculous example, if I override the `__repr__()` method on a class called `RealAnimals` as `return "Unicorns, " + ', '.join(self.animal_list)`, then `"Unicorns" in str(ra)` returns True regardless of whether or not it's in the list. It's best not to assume what the object is going to print.

Comment: Relying on the string representation of a sequence is fragile. What if it works for this example, but it doesn't work for a hyphenated word because, unguessed (and untested) by any of us, the string representation escapes hyphens, or replaces them with Unicode hyphens? Or, what if different versions of `ntlk` use different string representations, so the code works here but not on the OP's other machine, or not in 3 months? The whole point of `str` is that it's meant to be human-readable rather than programmatically processable. Whereas actual values have well-defined comparison rules.